# Why don't I see my "Hello World" code on Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jdk

I am new to Java, but how come I do not see my code on Netbeans?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have just built JavaApplication1 not HelloWorld.

Answer (score 2):

> I am new to Java, but how come I do not see my code on Netbeans?

Your screenshot indicates that you built and ran **javaApplication1.java** 
 You need to build and run **HelloWorld.java** instead.